# CSS id selector doesn't applied to a component inside jsf page

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2

I have these css file with an id selector as follows:

```
#globalFilter {
margin-left: 995px;
margin-top:-30px;
width:320px;
height:20px;
font-size: 11px;
}
```

and the component with the mentioned id is as follows:

```
        <p:inputText id="globalFilter" value="Search" />
```

and it's inside a  called `notifybar`, the problem is that the properties in the selector doesn't applied on the component when the page is rendered

Note: the css file is loaded successfully and the component with id="globalFilter" exists in the view source mode

also these class selector doesn't applied to another component inside the page:

selector:

```
.underlineOnHover{
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

component:

```
    <h:outputLink id="notify"styleClass="underlineOnHover">
        <h:outputText value="notifications" />
    </h:outputLink>
```

also these is the generated html for the `<p:inputText id="globalFilter">`

```
<input id="globalFilter" name="globalFilter" type="text" value="Search" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" /><script id="globalFilter_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw('InputText','widget_globalFilter',{id:'globalFilter'});</script>
```

Comment: Are you styling the `<input>` anywhere else in your CSS?

Comment: No i wrote only these selector

Comment: Can you post your code up to the enclosing `<h:form>`?

Comment: an edit has been made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably its client id is not `globalFilter`, but rather `form:globalFilter`: it could have some naming containers in its ancestry. Just check out the generated HTML in a browser tool, like Firebug, to assure that it is so.

There are three remedies I can think of:

1. Use `styleClass` attribute instead: it accepts a CSS class rather than I'd selector, like in `<h:inputText styleClass="your-css-class" />`.
2. Use absolute client id by checking out the generated HTML in your CSS file, like `#form:globalFilter { ... }`.
3. Use `prependId="false"` attribute of your enclosing `<h:form>` so that the client id would be exactly `globalFilter`.